# TypeScript - third party libraries without definition files - is intellisense possible?

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellisense, webstorm, definitelytyped

The IDE I am using is WebStorm, but my question applies to any IDE.

---

I am installing some third party node modules to my project, and some do not have definition files available in DefinitelyTyped, or the definition files are outdated. The workaround I currently use for these libraries is one of the following:

1. declare the third party namespace/module as type *any*
2. declare a minimal definition which specifies the methods that I use which the library exposes. e.g:

   ```
   declare module 'redux-simple-router' {
     export function syncHistory(history: any): any

     export function routeReducer(): any
   }
   ```

2 is a bit superior than 1 in that it gives more information, and I am able to get auto-complete for the method names for instance, however, both methods are very much inferior to what WebStorm currently offers if I use non-Typescript ES6 with Babel. Is there any way that I can combine both intellisense ways in my project?

In other words, what I'm looking for is a way to tell WebStorm: for each import, if you have type-definition use it, if not - use the regular intellisense (i.e search for imports in node_modules).

I hope my question is phrased in a way which makes sense, if it's confusing in any way please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is there any way that I can combine both intellisense ways in my project?
```

well... Currently, if WebStorm can resolve certain function using both typescript stubs and node_modules, results are merged (might result in 'several definitions' on attempt to go to declaration, etc.). If resolving from node_modules is impossible due to the way module is defined (dynamically, etc.), only typescript stubs are used.
In future, we plan to only use stubs to completion/error checking, but (if possible) use node_modules when navigating to definition/searching for usages